# Using gensim doc2vec with Keras Conv1d. ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, gensim

Im currently trying to implement a convolutional lstm network using keras. Instead of using keras' embedding layer, I used Gensim's doc2vec embeddings and created input data from it.

**preprocessing**

```
preprocessed_train = utils.preprocess_text(train_vect)
preprocessed_test = utils.preprocess_text(test_vect)

print preprocessed_train[0]

result: [u'snes_classic', u'preorders_open', u'later_month', u'ever_since', u'nintendo', u'announce', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'earlier', u'fan', u'desperate', u'register', u'interest', u'ensure', u'come', u'launch', u'however', u'although', u'system', u'pre-orders', u'make', u'available', u'retailers', u'every', u'store', u'plan', u'sell', u'console', u'allow', u'people', u'place', u'pre-orders', u'yet', u'today', u'though', u'nintendo', u'confirm', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'pre-orders', u'soon', u'available', u'fan', u'post_official', u'facebook', u'company', u'console', u'make', u'available_pre-order', u'various_retailers', u'late', u'month', u'nintendo', u'appreciate', u'incredible', u'anticipation', u'hardware', u'reference', u'fact', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'already', u'sell', u'many', u'place', u'across_globe', u'unfortunately', u'nintendo', u'clarify', u'exactly', u'retailers', u'open', u'snes_classic', u'pre-orders', u'provide', u'exact_date', u'however', u'stand_reason', u'wal-mart', u'retailers', u'force', u'cancel_pre-orders', u'hardware', u'website', u'error', u'saw', u'go_live', u'prematurely', u'currently_unclear', u'wal-mart', u'help', u'cancel', u'reservations', u'sign-up', u'pre-orders', u'go_live', u'properly', u'month', u'appreciate', u'incredible', u'anticipation', u'exist', u'super_nintendo', u'entertainment_system', u'super_nes', u'classic', u'post', u'nintendo', u'tuesday_august', u'1', u'2017', u'post', u'nintendo', u'mention', u'ship', u'significant_amount', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'units', u'retailers', u'launch', u'company', u'make', u'units', u'available', u'throughout', u'balance', u'calendar', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'first', u'announce', u'nintendo', u'explain', u'make', u'units', u'nes_classic', u'constantly', u'sell', u'leave', u'many', u'glad', u'nintendo', u'offer_clarification', u'others', u'however', u'remain_unconvinced', u'nintendo', u'able', u'keep', u'demand', u'console', u'incredibly_hard', u'fan', u'place', u'legitimate', u'order', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'end', u'even_harder', u'find', u'throughout', u'scalpers', u'place', u'pre-orders', u'pick', u'console', u'post-launch', u'order', u'sell', u'higher_price', u'later_date', u'retailers', u'like', u'ebay', u'enforce_rule', u'scalpers', u'unclear_whether', u'enough', u'snes_classic', u'edition', u'launch', u'september_29', u'2017_source', u'nintendo', u'facebook']
```

**data labels**

```
y_test = [x for x in test_data['slabel']]
y_train = [x for x in train_data['slabel']]

y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)

result:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

**load doc2vec model**

```
doc2vec_model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec.load('./doc2vec-models/dmbbv_300_epoch_500_size_model')
```

**infer data and create input vectors**. The *infer_vector* function creates the document embeddings based on the doc2vec model that I created.

```
X_train = []
for text in preprocessed_train:
    inferred_vec = doc2vec_model.infer_vector(text)
    X_train.append(inferred_vec)

X_test = []
for text in preprocessed_test:
    inferred_vec = doc2vec_model.infer_vector(text)
    X_test.append(inferred_vec)
```

**reshape data**

```
X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1]))
X_train.shape,X_test.shape

result: ((1476, 1, 500), (370, 1, 500))
```

**building model**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 128,
                 kernel_size = 5,
                 input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]), 
                 padding = 'valid',
                 activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(LSTM(X_train.shape[1],return_sequences = True, 
               implementation=2, 
               kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(0.001),
               activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)
              ))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences = True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences = True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences = True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(LSTM(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adamax',metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 'accuracy'])
```

then I get this error

---

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-488-b29db30c3ee7> in <module>()
      5 #                  use_bias=True,
      6                  padding = 'valid',
----> 7                  activation = 'relu'))
      8 model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
      9 model.add(LSTM(X_train.shape[1],return_sequences = True, 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.pyc in add(self, layer)
    434                 # and create the node connecting the current layer
    435                 # to the input layer we just created.
--> 436                 layer(x)
    437 
    438             if len(layer.inbound_nodes) != 1:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    594 
    595             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 596             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    597             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    598 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.pyc in call(self, inputs)
    154                 padding=self.padding,
    155                 data_format=self.data_format,
--> 156                 dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate[0])
    157         if self.rank == 2:
    158             outputs = K.conv2d(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in conv1d(x, kernel, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate)
   3114         strides=(strides,),
   3115         padding=padding,
-> 3116         data_format=tf_data_format)
   3117     return x
   3118 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.pyc in convolution(input, filter, padding, strides, dilation_rate, name, data_format)
    670         dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
    671         padding=padding,
--> 672         op=op)
    673 
    674 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.pyc in with_space_to_batch(input, dilation_rate, padding, op, filter_shape, spatial_dims, data_format)
    336       raise ValueError("dilation_rate must be positive")
    337     if np.all(const_rate == 1):
--> 338       return op(input, num_spatial_dims, padding)
    339 
    340   # We have two padding contributions. The first is used for converting "SAME"

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.pyc in op(input_converted, _, padding)
    662           data_format=data_format,
    663           strides=strides,
--> 664           name=name)
    665 
    666     return with_space_to_batch(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.pyc in _non_atrous_convolution(input, filter, padding, data_format, strides, name)
    114           padding=padding,
    115           data_format=data_format_2d,
--> 116           name=scope)
    117     elif conv_dims == 2:
    118       if data_format is None or data_format == "NHWC":

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.pyc in conv1d(value, filters, stride, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, data_format, name)
   2011     result = gen_nn_ops.conv2d(value, filters, strides, padding,
   2012                                use_cudnn_on_gpu=use_cudnn_on_gpu,
-> 2013                                data_format=data_format)
   2014     return array_ops.squeeze(result, [spatial_start_dim])
   2015 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.pyc in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, data_format, name)
    395                                 strides=strides, padding=padding,
    396                                 use_cudnn_on_gpu=use_cudnn_on_gpu,
--> 397                                 data_format=data_format, name=name)
    398   return result
    399 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    765         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    766                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 767                          op_def=op_def)
    768         if output_structure:
    769           outputs = op.outputs

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   2630                     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   2631     if compute_shapes:
-> 2632       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
   2633     self._add_op(ret)
   2634     self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   1909       shape_func = _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op
   1910 
-> 1911   shapes = shape_func(op)
   1912   if shapes is None:
   1913     raise RuntimeError(

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in call_with_requiring(op)
   1859 
   1860   def call_with_requiring(op):
-> 1861     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
   1862 
   1863   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op = call_with_requiring

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn)
    593     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
    594                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
--> 595                                   require_shape_fn)
    596     if not isinstance(res, dict):
    597       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    657       missing_shape_fn = True
    658     else:
--> 659       raise ValueError(err.message)
    660 
    661   if missing_shape_fn:

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for 'conv1d_55/convolution/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,500], [1,5,500,128].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the input shape. Instead of `(None, 1, 500)` you can try with `(None, 500, 1)`.

You can tell that by looking at the exception

```
`Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for 'conv1d'`
```

the kernel (5) is bigger than the second dimension.

Comment: It did work. thanks a lot. but Im not sure how it worked. could you please explain it if you would?

Comment: My answer was just meant to say "it fails because your kernel is bigger than the dimension it is suppose to pass through". But in your model, you need to deside if that dimension was correct in the first place. If you look at [keras' documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv1d) it gives you a hint to use the dimensions like this: (None, time, feature_size). In your case time could be the amount of tokens and feature size the embedding size.

Comment: The amount of tokens assuming you use a word model, but since you are using Doc2Vec, do you have a time dimension at all?

Comment: hmm in my case. I am using doc2vec and "time" isn't really the amount of tokens but the number of documents. which means that the features are representations of the documents. and no I don't think i have a time dimension. is there something wrong with what I'm doing? should I be using conv2d instead?

Comment: But if I understand correctly, lstm requires a time dimension, otherwise you won't have sequences.

Comment: @VincentPakson can you provide the full code as a Gist? would really appreciate it!

Comment: Well the other parts of the code are just preprocessing the documents that I have. Well this answer already answered my question so it's fine.